# Mysql join and filter by multiple column values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have the following query

```
select events.* from clients
inner join events on events.client_id = clients.id
inner join salons on clients.business_id = businesses.id
where businesses.campaign_id = 27
```

which produces

```
id  client_id   category
3605    608     0
3606    608     1
3607    608     2
3608    608     3
3611    609     0
3612    609     1
3613    609     2
3614    609     3
3615    609     5
3616    609     6
3617    610     0
3618    610     1
3619    610     2
3620    610     3
3621    610     5
3622    610     6
```

I need to select all clients that have an event with category 0, 1, 2 or 3 but not with category 4, 5 or 6.

I'm thinking that maybe there's a way to group together the event rows without losing access to all the category data.

So with the above data the desired result would be:

```
id  client_id   category
3605    608     0
3606    608     1
3607    608     2
3608    608     3
```

Ultimately I'm only interested in clients that have some events but not others so results with client_id of 609 and 610 would be omitted since they include a category of 0, 1, 2 or 3 and not 4, 5, or 6.

Comment: Please add the desired result.

Comment: Your question is not so clear, can you explain what your desired output would be as @PM77-1 asked?

Comment: @KJF as you see you are already receiving answers on different problems; don't make us guess what you need!

Comment: schema is incomplete.. business is another table and salons another table.. where is the join there?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis apologies, I've updated the question to include the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation was clearly needed. I posted an answer based on it.

Answer (score 1):

From your sample data, I assume that category can take on values between `0..6`. Given that, you could group by `client_id` and accept only those where `max(category) <= 3`; this makes sure that there is no category between `4..6`, and that there is at least one between `1..3`.

```
select events.client_id from clients
inner join events on events.client_id = clients.id
inner join salons on clients.business_id = businesses.id
where businesses.campaign_id = 27
group by client_id
having max(category)<=3
```

If you additionally want to "keep the events data", you could use above query as a subquery:

```
select events.* from clients
inner join events on events.client_id = clients.id
inner join salons on clients.business_id = businesses.id
where businesses.campaign_id = 27
      and events.clients.id in (
    select events.client_id from clients
    inner join events on events.client_id = clients.id
    inner join salons on clients.business_id = businesses.id
    where businesses.campaign_id = 27
    group by client_id
    having max(category)<=3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select events.* from clients
inner join events on events.client_id = clients.id
inner join salons on clients.business_id = businesses.id
where businesses.campaign_id = 27
and events.categoryid in (0,1,2,3)
and not exists 
(select * from events x 
 where x.client_id = clients.id and events.categoryid in (4,5,6)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select clients.id from clients
inner join events on events.client_id = clients.id
inner join salons on clients.business_id = businesses.id
where businesses.campaign_id = 27
group by clients.id
having SUM( CASE WHEN category in ( 0,1,2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) = 4;
```

Comment: Which requirement fulfils the `having` clause? And what about the "without losing access to all category data" part of the question?